# Can not fetch json data from the spring-boot response

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

I create some spring + react.js application and one of the main function of that is show news from the MySQL database. But when I try to fetch JSON using react function that returns me nothing.

I added 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json' to the fetch React function, but that not help.
React component:

```
class News extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        news: []
    }
};

ourFunction = () =>{
   const response  = fetch('/news/all',{
       headers: {
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'Accept': 'application/json'
       }
   });
    console.log(response);
    const body =  response.json;
    console.log(body);
    this.setState({news : body });
    console.log(this.state.news);
};

render() {
    return (
        <div className="news">
            <span onClick={this.ourFunction}>Click{}</span>
            <div className="news_bar"> Новини</div>
            {defaultNewsData.map(({title, content, date}) => <AccordionContainer
                title={title}
                content={content}
                date={date}
            />)}
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default News;
```

Spring controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/news")
public class NewsController {

@Autowired
private NewsRepository newsRepository;

@GetMapping("/add")
public String addNewNews(@RequestParam String title, @RequestParam String content){
    News news = new News();
    news.setTitle(title);
    news.setContent(content);
    newsRepository.save(news);
    return "News Saved";
}

@GetMapping(path = "/all")
public Iterable<News> getAllNews(){
    return newsRepository.findAll();
}
}
```

Expected: to fetch JSON object to the javascript and parse it to the HTML.
Actual: I receive nothing, that is shown on the console.

Comment: Are you sure that newsRepository.findAll(); returns anything?

Comment: What happens when you call this endpoint directly, not via react. Are you sure you're getting JSON output?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli it exactly returns news because I use /add controller for adding news first and after /all to see it.

Comment: @DanielTung that return me JSON: [{"id":2,"title":"LabolatoryWorker","content":"Last","date":null},{"id":3,"title":"LabolatoryWorker","content":"Last","date":null}]

Comment: When running the React code check your browser network tab to see what's going on behind the scenes. It sounds like the data should be getting returned so the issue is with how react is processing it.

Comment: @DanielTung I receive that in the network:
In the header comes JSON as in the pevious comment
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/news/all
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: [::1]:8080
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 27 Jun 2019 17:59:42 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,ru-RU;q=0.8,ru;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:8080
Referer: http://localhost:8080/

Comment: Problem resolved. 
I have received promises format using that endpoint. I use that solution for the problem:

       _ourFunction = () =>{
       const response = fetch('/news/all',{
           headers : {
               'Content-Type': 'application/json',
               'Accept': 'application/json'
           }
       }).then((rs)=>{console.log(rs.json().then((a)=>{console.log(a,'111')}))});
        //console.log(response);
        const body =  response.json;
        console.log(body);
        this.setState({news : body });
        console.log(this.state.news);
    };_